# Creating Curved Geometry? - Modeling Question

Tags: modeling

Simple question—how would I go about modeling the left and right edges of this radio's handle? If the subdivision modifier is required, how should the model look before applying the modifier? How should it be edited afterwards?

[image: Text]

Comment: Modeling the main body of it doesn’t sound too complicated, and with a Boolean operation, you can probably get the indent on the inside. Add some bevel or some subdivision, and there you are. I’ll test out this theory later.

Comment: Voting to close as this is a question about modeling a specific shape and is not likely to be useful for a wide audience. I'd suggest asking this on an online forum such as [Blender Artists Community](https://blenderartists.org).

Answer (score 0):

Create an angle:

[image]

Bevel it:

[image]

Extrude:

[image]

Extrude to give thickness:

[image]

Bevel the edges, etc:

[image]